# "Invalid key resource URL" When adding key for Elementary tweaks

Tags: apt, ppa, tweak-tool, gpg

Hello every one I recently intalled Elementary OS and now I get some issues when trying to add new repositorys.

I wanted to install Elementary OS tweaks and I'm getting the following error

```
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.tbWHnlELWh/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 
c42d52715a84c7d0d02fc740c1d89326b1c71ab9
gpg: Schlüssel C1D89326B1C71AB9: Öffentlicher Schlüssel "Launchpad PPA for Philip Scott" 
importiert
gpg: Anzahl insgesamt bearbeiteter Schlüssel: 1
gpg:               importiert: 1
gpg: invalid key resource URL '/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.tbWHnlELWh/home:manuelschneid3r.asc.gpg'
gpg: Schlüsselblockhilfsmittel`(null)': Allgemeiner Fehler
gpg: key 7721F63BD38B4796: 2 Beglaubigungen wegen fehlender Schlüssel nicht geprüft
gpg: key 1488EB46E192A257: 1 Beglaubigung wegen fehlendem Schlüssel nicht geprüft
gpg: key 1488EB46E192A257: 1 Beglaubigung wegen fehlendem Schlüssel nicht geprüft
gpg: key 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32: 3 Beglaubigungen wegen fehlender Schlüssel nicht geprüft
gpg: key D94AA3F0EFE21092: 3 Beglaubigungen wegen fehlender Schlüssel nicht geprüft
gpg: key 871920D1991BC93C: 1 Beglaubigung wegen fehlendem Schlüssel nicht geprüft
gpg: Anzahl insgesamt bearbeiteter Schlüssel: 13
gpg:       ignorierte neue Schlüssel: 13
```

When using the following command: `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv c42d52715a84c7d0d02fc740c1d89326b1c71ab9`

I tried to follow the instruction on the tweaks github page: https://github.com/pantheon-tweaks/pantheon-tweaks

I am also new to linux and don't know if the error is maybe on my side here.

Furtheremore I got a similar issue with nodejs: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md
Therefore it could be a configuration issue in the os.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1247655/1117671) on AskUbuntu should fix the issue.
Apparently this is caused by a GPG signing key, perhaps for Albert Launcher?
Just delete the mentioned `manuelschneid3r` key from your list of trusted keys.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/home:manuelschneid3r.*
```

If the key is indeed for the Albert Launcher, you should be able to safely re-add it by following the directions [here](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home:manuelschneid3r&package=albert) for the appropriate version of Ubuntu, i.e. on elementaryOS 5.1 use the following command.

```
curl -fsSL https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:manuelschneid3r/xUbuntu_18.04/Release.key \
  | gpg --dearmor \
  | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/home_manuelschneid3r.gpg > /dev/null
```

If you are on elementaryOS 5.1 Hera, the following commands should add the [elementary-tweaks PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ephilip.scott/+archive/ubuntu/elementary-tweaks) to your system and install the tweaks package.

```
sudo apt -y install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository -uy ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks
sudo apt -y install elementary-tweaks
```

In elementaryOS 6 Odin it looks like elementary-tweaks has become [pantheon-tweaks](https://launchpad.net/%7Ephilip.scott/+archive/ubuntu/pantheon-tweaks).
For elementaryOS 6 you should use the following commands to install the tweaks utility.

```
sudo apt -y install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository -uy ppa:philip.scott/pantheon-tweaks
sudo apt -y install pantheon-tweaks
```